# How to differentiate between a method and a function?

Tags: javascript, oop

I have always been confused between these two. From what I understand, methods always use dot notation like:

```
$( "li.third-item" ).nextAll().addBack().css( "background-color", "red" );
```

In this case, `nextAll()`, `addBack()` and `.css()` are all methods.

Similarly, functions are called directly. Like,

```
make_tea();
```

I want to know with certainty whether something is a function or a method by looking at how it is used. Does using `PersonOne.run_now()` always guarantee that `run_now()` is a method? Can `run_now()` still be a function if we are using a `.` to access it?

My question is "Does a function become a method when we are using `.` to call it?"

Comment: JavaScript methods are the actions that can be performed on objects.

A JavaScript method is a property containing a function definition. [src](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_methods.asp)

Comment: In Javascript, methods and functions are nearly identical -- like previous stated: methods are simply properties attached to objects which is described as a function (the only difference is that you attach methods to types or to variables, and functions are able to stand alone)

Comment: In fact, all functions are methods because they are part of the window object i think

Comment: @Jonasw: that assumes the javascript is running in a browser.  As far as I am aware, js running in Node would not necessarily have a window object.

Comment: @Jonasw Counter example: `function () { function foo() {}; }`

Comment: Are you thinking of the difference between a 'prototype' extension method and a function call?

E.g. `Array.prototype.shout` vs shout(arr)

https://jsfiddle.net/a6787yny/

Comment: @deceze: so in fact everything that is declared in an anonymous function is not part of an object right?

Comment: @Jonasw Anything that is declared in any sort of function and is not attached to an object is not part of the global object.

Comment: @deceze ok ive got it. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Methods* are simply `function` *references* stored in an `object` *property*. *Method*  in Javascript is merely a concept, not actually an existing syntactical part. Also, there is no `method` keyword in Javascript.

```
function foo() { /* whatever */ }

var bar = {};
bar.baz = foo;

// You'd consider this a function call
foo();

// While the following is actually syntactically also a function call
// you might consider baz a "method of the bar object"
bar.baz();
// and thus bar.baz() would then be a "method call".
```

Please not that to access a property of an object you have two possible ways: `object.property` and `object[propertyName]` where `propertyName` is a `string` containing the name of the property.

So

```
bar.baz()
```

achieves exactly the same as and is identical to

```
bar["baz"]().
```

Comment: Does using a `.` like I did in the question, guarantee that this particular function is actually a method?

Comment: Note that Javascript is extremely fluid in this area… `var f = o.f;`, `f.call(o)`…

Comment: Why would you even care? Syntactically, in JS there is no difference between a function and a method.

Comment: @connexo So, I can use both the terms interchangeably in JavaScript?

Comment: @Neena Vivek: every function that is declared inside of an object (the window object too) is a method. Just functions that are declared inside of functions (or methods) arent methods.

Comment: A function that is stored in the property of an object is commonly referred to as a method of that object (that is, something that the object can perform).

Comment: Re your new example code: I would consider the latter a *method call*. How that method got attached to the object and whether it actually interacts with the object (uses `this`) is somewhat besides the point. If you're going to postulate that methods are "function references stored in an object", then it's a method.

Comment: @connexo: in your example foo() is equal to window.foo() ...

Comment: @Jonasw Again, your scope is limited to the browser. JS exists outside of the browser as well.

Comment: But i bet this is the area the OP is mostly writing code...

Comment: @deceze trying to be precise, I have added *method call* explanantion in code comments.

Comment: Well, *syntactically* it's a method call. Assume you have no prior knowledge how `bar` got assembled; `bar.baz()` is quite obviously a method call. (The distinction doesn't really matter though… :))

Comment: I disagree here. Since there is no syntactical, lexical part of JS that is a  `method`, it 's merely **conceptually**  a *method call* , not *syntactically* . Syntactically it can only be a function call.